# navigator.geolocation don't work on mobile chrome

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

I have a trouble with geolocation on mobile site. On iPhone with safari work fine. On Android with chrome browser don't work (but with mozilla all fine). I think this trouble is related with HTTP (chrome geolocation work oly with HTTPS)

```
var get_location = function(change_location) {

if (navigator.geolocation) {

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;

  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  var location = {};

  geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if(results.length > 0) {
          for(var i = 0; i < results[2].address_components.length - 1; i++) {
            switch(results[2].address_components[i].types[0]) {
                case "locality":
                  location.city = results[2].address_components[i].long_name;
                  break;
                case "administrative_area_level_1":
                  location.region = results[2].address_components[i].long_name;
                  break;
                case "country":
                  location.country = results[2].address_components[i].long_name;
                  break;
              }
          }
          change_location(location);
        } else {
          console.log('No location found');
        }
    }
  });
});


} else {
    console.log('No GPS');
  }
}
```

Comment: We (Chrome) haven't landed the HTTPS only requirement for the navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition API yet so it should not be https only. In Chrome do you get 'No GPS' or another state?

Comment: I don't get 'No GPS'. Don't work navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition in chrome mobile and don't have another state

Comment: Do you hit the `var lat = position.coords.latitude;` if you add a breakpoint.